# login once and skip login layout everytime app starts after first login

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am writing an android application where I want to integrate facebook login using  facebook sdk 3.I have tried lots of tutorial but now successful.Can anyone give me a 
complete guide by which I can achieve following :

1. Login activity:

   If user logs in once from this activity it will go to home activity.Guess user has   logged in  for the first time and now on home activity and   after few moments user has closed the app. From now every time user starts the app, app will skip the login activity and starts home activity.  If user changes his password from facebook.com and then starts the android app then I want to show the login activity.
2. Home activity:

   I have a logout button on this activity.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook is holding that value in session,

So you have to just check that `is_session_valid()` or not and base on that response you can switch your activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can store login status (true / false) in [sharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values). Now for second requirement two cases may occur.

1. When user left the **HomeActivity**, the app goes in background it is **alive** but is in **passive** state, In this case you don't need to do anything when user relaunches App from recent tasks or from launcher Android will automatically start the **last Activity** user viewed (i.e. HomeActivity in your case).
2. While the App was in background someone **killed** it i.e. Android OS for claiming memory for some other App, you restarted phone, some task killer killed App etc. In that case when user starts App again, Android will start the default **launcher** Activity i.e. **LoginActivity** their you need to check  the variable you stored in **SharedPreferences** inside OnResume of LoginActivity. If user was already logged in just start the HomeActivity else start the normal behavior.

Not just the boolean variable you can store **anything** you think will be **needed** for starting **HomeActivity**.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to keep track of tokens and see if the token is still valid. If token is not valid the user need to login again. So when you request a token for the first time save it in the user defaults of the application. And just check next time for validity of the token.

See here for login specific information:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/

For more information see at chapter 6
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

Comment: how I will check a token is valid or not ? Guess I have 2 days to expire accesstoken, but if i change my password in 1 day then what will then ?

Comment: If you make a new request such as /me request when the token is invalid you will get an OAuth exception. Catch this by showing this to the user and direct to login.